# how can i make my button clickable area bigger

Tags: html

i wanna know why my button clickable area is bugged, i can only click a small area, and it works terrible.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-dark boton-carrito" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight"><img src="../multimedia/shopping-cart.png" alt="" class="foto_carrito"></button>

.boton-carrito {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.foto_carrito {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
```

Im using bootstrap too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you make the area of your button bigger using padding (options: p-1, p-2, p-3, p-4, p-5) instead of using "boton-carrito"?

```
class="p-2"
```

if you're using React JS:

```
className="p-2"
```

Good luck!